# UPDATE запрос к MySQL из Java

Tags: java, mysql

Есть такой метод

```
String query = "UPDATE table1 SET name = (?), phone = (?) WHERE id = 1";
ConnectionDB conDB = new ConnectionDB();
Connection connect = conDB.geyConnection();
try {
    PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connect.prepareStatement(query);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, this.name);
    preparedStatement.setString(1, this.phone);
    preparedStatement.executeUpdate();
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

В данном методе, обновляться будут оба поля, даже если они остались прежними. Просто произойдет перезапись поля новыми значениями. Но это здесь я привел пример с двумя полями, а что делать если полей куча, и в каждом большое количество информации. Отправлять их все, будет наверное плохо для БД, ведь посути, БД будет выполнять бесполезную работу. Как сделать проверку на изменение перед отправкой этого запроса к БД? Если допустим, есть объект который содержит данные этой записи.

```
User user = User.selectInfo(1);
```

Оба объекта, естественно, одного класса. Объект user содержит в своих полях значение нужной строки из БД. Их можно сравнивать. Но я чет не пойму, как потом составить запрос, что бы поля которые не изменились, не отправлялись в запросе

Comment: делать это руками довольно сложно - попробуйте использовать какой-нибудь ORM фреймворк

Comment: как вариант подключите Hibernate и будет вам счастье)

Comment: *В данном методе, обновляться будут оба поля, даже если они остались прежними. Просто произойдет перезапись поля новыми значениями.* Это ошибочное утверждение, потому что обновляются не поля, а записи. Правильное утверждение - "Запись будет обновлена, если изменится значение хотя бы одного поля.". Рассмотрите свои мысли с учётом этого факта.

Comment: @Akina я понимаю, что обновляется запись полностью, при изменении какого нить поля в ней. Но можно ж изменить только одно поле в записи, которое отличается, а не менять все на теже самые значения

Comment: Сперва подумайте - ГДЕ выяснится, что старое значение равно новому, и это поле в этой записи обновления не требует. Вариантов всего два. Если на клиенте (другой вопрос - откуда на клиенте старое состояние, но допустим, что оно имеется) - ну тогда перед апдейтом проверяйте, и выбирайте из пачки запросов только тот, который требует передачи на сервер новых значений только для изменяющихся полей. Ну а если на SQL-сервере - так новое значение по-любому надо на него от клиента передать, чтобы ему было с чем сравнивать...